# Inconsistent VBA Error Message Box?

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

It seems that the message box that VBA pops-up when an unhandled exception occurs behaves differently depending on... something? To see what I mean, create a new .xlsm, <del>then create a standard module `Module1`; paste inside this code</del> then paste inside `Sheet1` Worksheet object this code:

```
Public Sub TestErrMsgBox()
    Debug.Print "Hello!"
    Call Err.Raise(Number:=vbObjectError, Source:="VBAProject.Sheet1",  Description:="Lorem Ipsum")
End Sub
```

On my Excel 2010 Professional Plus, calling the subroutine in the VBE's "Immediate" (Ctrl+G) window:

<del>Call Module1.TestErrMsgBox</del>

```
Call Sheet1.TestErrMsgBox
```

will show the error message *Automation Error / Invalid OLEVERB structure*.

Now, if one calls directly the Raise method from in the "Immediate" window:

```
Call Err.Raise(Number:=vbObjectError, Source:="VBAProject.Sheet1",  Description:="Lorem Ipsum")
```

it will show the (expected) error message *Lorem Ipsum*.

What exactly changes in the error handling, or in the `Err` object, from the first case to the last? and how it may be manipulated? I figured out that in the first case the message depends only on the `Number` argument in `Raise` call, but still it doesn't explain...

I find this a bit annoying, because I expected my messages displayed, not something else. There's always available the Pokemon approach (catching all the exceptions and showing custom MessageBoxes based on `Err` properties), but I'd like to understand what happens. :-)

**Later edit:**

The behavior described above happens when "Error Trapping" is set on "Break on Unhandled Errors." Once I put "Break on All Errors" it displays the correct message, with the "Debug" button available; however, this is not a good idea, to break execution on every error...

Also, thanks to the feedback from [Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k), [roryap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2704659/roryap) and [Doug Glancy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293078/doug-glancy) I figured out that this happens when the `TestErrMsgBox` subroutine is called from within a Worksheet object, not from a standard Module as I incorrectly reported the first time. The posting is fixed; however, the question is still there. :-)

Comment: Odd, works for me in 2k7, however you are supposed to *add* a value to the base code: `Number:=vbObjectError + 1234`, try it that way?

Comment: What happens if you hit the "Debug" button when the "Invalid OLEVERB structure" error message appears?  Where does the code break?

Comment: @Alex K.: Oh, I tried that... the message the is displays in this case (when raising the exception from the subroutine) is plain "Automation Error", no other description... I guess that, for `vbObjectError + 1234` it has no predefined supplemental information.

Comment: @roryap: Funny, when I configure "Error trapping" to "Break on All Errors" the message box shows the expected "Lorem Ipsum", and the highlighted line is the `Raise` call... The setting used to be "Break on Unhandled Errors"

Comment: Strange.  I can't reproduce your issue on mine.

Comment: It's behaving the same in both situations for me. Excel 2010 Pro, Win 7, Break on Unhandled Errors.

Comment: @roryap: The Excel version that I use is 14.0.6112.5000 (32-bit). Unfortunately I cannot post print screens (company policy)...

Comment: @roryap & Doug Glancy: Hmm... okay, could you paste the code to a worksheet code (let's say `Sheet1`) and run in the "Immediate" window: `Sheet1.TestErrMsgBox`, please?

Comment: I did that, and came up with an answer, or at least a solution :).

Comment: All these requests to try things, and then when I answer, nothing? :-)

Comment: @DougGlancy -- Hey man, I'd accept your answer if I could.  I think you nailed it.

Comment: @Doug Glancy: Sorry for testing your patience, I just couldn't give feedback while I was returning from work. :-) I will comment on your answer also. Again, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Of course. I was aiming for humorously fussy, but may have missed the mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it happens when your Sub is in a Sheet module and you've set the VBE to Break on Unhandled Errors, has to do with the fact that a Sheet module is a class module. Set Error Trapping to Break in Class Modules, and it will behave correctly.

I always use this setting anyways, so I can debug inside UserForms and classes.

Searching "VBA err.raise invalid oleverb structure break in class module" seems to support the fact that it's related to class modules.

Comment: 1) Thanks again for looking out for a *solution*; however, I would like to know the *reason* for this behavior. I will keep the question open for 1 more day, just in case someone could give an explanation; if this doesn't happen, I will accept your answer, of course. I don’t want to seem ungrateful, just want to have a chance to find out something I’d like to know. ;-)

Comment: 2) *(This point is on general principle, and not a criticism to your answer)* The "Break on Class Modules" is okay for code written for personal use; the normal user of an .xlsm shouldn’t be concerned with tracing into somebody’s else code though.

Comment: 3) Also, "Break on Class Modules" might make impossible some code that *could do* some error handling. E.g. one has a file that may have 2 formats, but basically contains the same information. The two formats are parsed by 2 classes `C1` and `C2`, that raise errors when the specific format is unrecognised. With "Break on Class Modules" it would be impossible to handle the situation as *if is not `C1` then try `C2`, if it’s not `C2` then stop the execution*.

Comment: 4) Given points 2) and 3), I think that would be best practice to avoid adding `Public` subroutines of functions to Excel objects, if those may throw exceptions (like I did). Just overriding the object's hooks (like `Worksheet_Activate`, for example) would do, eventually adding `Private` methods that have all their possible errors handled.

Comment: Very good points. Regarding other users having to set it to Break on Class Modules, that's never been an issue for me because I have error handling that deals with it. However for debugging, it's very useful.

Comment: Regarding Public code in Excel objects, yeah, I don't do that. Finally, I'm curious about the actual answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Declare sub as friend in class module instead of public

Comment: Why does that work? My assumption was that different result of an exception is because of the ability to instantiate Sheet/ThisWorkbook, but not Module. As per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673333/how-can-i-capture-a-microsoft-access-vba-debug-error-from-my-c-sharp-code/9709082#9709082